# Get service status from remote server using powershell

Tags: powershell, service, remote-server

How to get the service status for a remote computer that needs a user name and password to log in?

I am trying to find a solution using the following code:

`$serviceStatus = get-service -ComputerName $machineName -Name $service`

The default syntax for the `get-service` command is:

```
Parameter Set: Default
Get-Service [[-Name] <String[]> ] [-ComputerName <String[]> ] [-DependentServices] [-Exclude <String[]> ] [-Include <String[]> ] [-RequiredServices] [ <CommonParameters>]

Parameter Set: DisplayName
Get-Service -DisplayName <String[]> [-ComputerName <String[]> ] [-DependentServices] [-Exclude <String[]> ] [-Include <String[]> ] [-RequiredServices] [ <CommonParameters>]

Parameter Set: InputObject
Get-Service [-ComputerName <String[]> ] [-DependentServices] [-Exclude <String[]> ] [-Include <String[]> ] [-InputObject <ServiceController[]> ] [-RequiredServices] [ <CommonParameters>]
```

This does not have an option for username and password.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As far as I know, Get-Service [doesn't accept a credential parameter](http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/567007/get-service-cmdlets-needs-a-credential-parameter). However, you can do it through [WMI](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176860.aspx):

```
$cred = get-Credential -credential <your domain user here>
Get-WMIObject Win32_Service -computer $computer -credential $cred
```

**Update after comment:**

You can save credentials as a securestring into a file, and then reload it  for manually creating a credential without having a prompt. See information [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4546.working-with-passwords-secure-strings-and-credentials-in-windows-powershell.aspx).

Comment: I am looking for something more silent. I wish to set the script up in TaskScheduler, and having a prompt for each server's password every 10 mins is not appropriate. :) Is there some way by which I can have the `Domein\Username` and `password` set up in the command itself.

Answer (score 14):

This also works:

```
net use \\server\c$ $password /USER:$username
$service = Get-Service $serviceName -ComputerName $server
```

Note that password should not be in a secure string.

Comment: Are you the only person who knows this? Why is this not the top answer for anyone asking about trying to administer remote machines running Windows?

Comment: ArtOfWarfare:: Totally Agreed. Spent a couple of hours researching this. Other methods of getting services on remote machine worked (different protocols?). I'm not entirely clear on how/why this worked. Can someone fill in the details for me? Thx

Comment: Wow, I spent like 2 days trying to find a way to authenticate to remote computer in PowerShell, question, how secure is it to authenticate like this?

Answer (score 0):

`Invoke-Command` can accomplish this.

```
$Cred = Get-Credential -Credential "<your domain user here>"
$ScriptBlock = {
    param($Service)
    Get-Service -Name "$Service"
}
$ServiceStatus = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $MachineName -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList "$Service"
```

Note that in order to pass the variable `$Service` to the `Get-Service` cmdlet in the script block, you have to declare the script block beforehand and define the `$Service` variable in the `param` block.  You can then pass the `$Service` argument into the script block via the `-ArgumentList` parameter.

`Invoke-Command` also supports running on multiple servers by supplying a comma delimited list of computers for the `-ComputerName` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Morton's answer, but using New-PSDrive for the share and Remove the share to tidy up.

```
New-PSDrive -Name tempDriveName –PSProvider FileSystem –Root “\\server\c$” -Credential $Cred
$service = Get-Service -Name $serviceName -ComputerName $MachineName 
Remove-PSDrive -Name tempDriveName
```